# How to know if the file is completely uploaded in ftp?

Tags: java, ftp

I am trying to download the files from ftp server using java FTPClient and FTPFile classes(commons-net.jar).How do i conclude if the file is partial or full(i.e., file is completely uploaded or not) using those classes?

Comment: This is a very old and well-known problem. 

There is no way to be absolutely certain a file being written by the FTP daemon is complete. It's even possible that the file transfer failed and then gets restarted and completed. You must poll the file's size and set a time limit, say 5 minutes. If the size does not change during that time you assume the file is complete.

Comment: ya didnot get any alternative may be this is only the alternative.